# Java : JLabel with text and icon

Tags: java, text, icons, label, jlabel

I would like to ask if it is possible in a single JLabel to have text icon text, what i mean is the icon to be in the center of my String text.

I managed to move text left or right of the icon but i cant figure out how to put the icon in the middle.

Comment: A JLabel has text and icon - you can have the label on top of the text, but not two text's and one icon. You can achieve this with 3 JLabel's together in the proper Layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> icon to be in the center of my String text

A `JLabel` has text and icon - you can have the label on top of the text, but not two text's and one icon. You can achieve the same look with 3 `JLabel`'s together in the proper Layout. For example, using a `BoxLayout`:

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
box.add(new JLabel("Text 1"));
JLabel image = new JLabel();
image.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
box.add(image);
box.add(new JLabel("Text 2"));
```

Alternatively, if you wish the text to be on top of the image you can do so by setting the appropriate alignments:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
label.setText("My Text");
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to ask if it is possible in a single JLabel to have text icon text

A JLabel can display simple HTML:

```
String html = "<html>before <img src=\"file:someFile.jpg\">after</html>";
JLabel label = new JLabel( html );
```

but HTML takes longer to render so you may want to consider the `BoxLayout` approach.